# Finding the zeroth Fourier coefficient using limit

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The $\text{n:th}$ Fourier coefficient (for the $\cos(nx)$ part) is defined by

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta) \cos(n\theta)d\theta.$$

Inserting $n=0$, we get

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta) d\theta.$$

which will give us the zeroth coefficient.

For the function $f(\theta)=(2a)^{-1},\, |\theta|\lt a$, we get

$$a_n = \cdots = \frac{\sin(na)}{\pi na},\, n \neq 0$$

However, taking the limit here as $n\to 0$ we get $a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}$ which is the same as we would get from setting $n=0$ before integrating.

My question is: does this work in general? Will you always get the correct (zeroth or other) coefficient by taking the limit rather than setting $n$ before integration?

I've thought about this a bit but I'm not sure about moving the limit inside the integration. I think that requires uniform convergence and I don't know if we have that in general.

Comment: No. In fact it actually makes no sense to talk about the limit of $a_n$ as $n$ tends to $0$, since $a_n$ is only defined for integers $n$. In the example you noticed, $a_0$ is _not_ the limit as $n$ tends to $0$ of $a_n$, it's just the limit of that particular _formula_ _representing_ $a_n$. In general there is no such formula, so the question of the limit of $a_n$ is simply meaningless.

Comment: Oh, obvious in hindsight... Thank you!

Comment: In your particular case, the formula you have works for real variables $n\ne 0$. So it is legitimate in this case to take a limit because $e^{in\theta}$ converges in $L^2$ to $1$ as $n\rightarrow 0$.